# What is mule's 'BlockingTransferInputStream' ? where is my actual payload?

Tags: java, mule, esb

I am using Mule ESB for content based routing within a service oriented project. i am migrating to New 'http based operation based connectors' as described [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector) but i cant find where my actuall payload is(actuall payload is a SOAP XML). when i print the payload i get this :

> org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.BlockingTransferInputStream@6f05894a

How can i get my desired payload? (SOAP XML)

this is my listener configuration :

```
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_request"  host="${MachineName}" port="${InboundPort}"  doc:name="HTTP request Configuration"  />       
    <flow name="RestEtryPoint">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_request"  path="/{name}" doc:name="HTTP"   />
        ........ //SOME CODE//
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in here http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/logger, 
what you're seeing is the stream that is used by the new http connector to improve performance. To check what the payload is, you need to consume the stream using something like an object-to-string transformer.

Also note that consuming your stream just to log a message may not be the recommended practice since it might affect the performance and memory footprint of your application.

Comment: yes your are right. i managed to solve it with object-to-byte-array-transformer

Comment: but now i am facing some other problems. seems that transformation messes with the package and : An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found.

Comment: All properties should still be available on the message. If this is not the case you can easily set an outbound property of your choice. I don't know what is exactly happening, however it would help if you explain what you're trying to achieve in your flow.